# How to set fetch limit on objects retrieved through to-many relationship?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-data

Say I have `User` and `File` with a to-many relationship called `files` in my Core Data stack. In my code, I load the user's files into an `NSArray` and iterate through the array performing various functions on the user's files. I have one user with 7,000 files.  I believe it would be good for my code to work on smaller "chunks" of the user's files rather than the whole 7,000 at one time.  I know there is a `fetchLimit` available (and that in SQLLite stores only the amount set by `fetchLimit` will be retrieved) - so, should I ignore the `files` relationship and instead do a limited fetch using `setFetchLimit`? Suggestions would be most welcome, thanks!

If anyone has sample code that achieves what I think I need, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

Relationships aren't fetches so a fetch limit does not apply. You could use a fetched property with a fetch limit but then you lose the advantages of the relationship.

However, I very much doubt you need to anything at all. Unless you've done testing and found that the large relationship is causing problems, there is no reason to expect it would. Core Data has a lot of tricks for conserving resources that is uses behind the scenes. I think it unlikely that a large simple relationship will actually cause problems. Core Data will not mindlessly load in 7,000 instantiated objects.

Test before you add extra complexity. Remember Donald Knuths' axoim *"premature optimization is the root of all evil."* Burning time to fix a problem you won't ever actually have is a waste and adds needless and dangerous complexity.

Comment: Thank you. In the end, I did have to ditch the usefulness of the relationship and use a fetch with a fetch limit, and that drastically improved the responsiveness of not only my app, but my entire machine while the app is running. Your answer did give me a useful insight, though, and at least I have an additional technique up my sleeve should the situation call for it

Comment: I think you might have something else going on. I've never seen a large relationship set bog an entire machine down. Instruments can tell you were the slowdown is coming from.